# AlpineJS - how to dynamically change the value in select based on the selected value in the previous select?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have two select options, the first are countries and the second are currencies.
My goal is to dynamically select the appropriate currency based on the selected country.
I use Codeigniter4 with Twig on work, I like AlpineJS and I want to start using it and I immediately got stuck on the first task..

**EDIT:**
I did it, this is what I wanted to achieve:

```
<div x-data="{ currency: '', currencies: {{ currencyArray|json_encode() }} }">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country">{{'country'|translate}}</label>
        <select id="country" name="country" class="form-select" aria-label="country"
              @change="currency = $event.target.options[$event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.currencyId">

            {% for country in countryArray %}
               <option value="{{ country.id }}" data-currency-id="{{ country.currency_id }}">
                   {{ country.description|capitalize|translate  }}
               </option>
            {% endfor %}

         </select>
    </div>
              
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="currrency">{{'currrency'|translate}}</label>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="currrency">
            <template x-for="c in currencies">
                <option 
                :value='c.id'
                :selected="c.id === currency"
                x-text="c.name + ' - ' + c.description"
                >
                </option>
            </template>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML. This has nothing to do with twig, codeignite nor php

Comment: @DarkBee The templating system used is Twig

Comment: @Pippo, that doesn't matter a problem/question should be self-contained. The question at hand is "how to dynamically change the value in select based on the selected value in the previous select?" which definitely can't be a twig problem, as twig is rendered serverside

Comment: @DarkBee My only consideration is that the templating system can interact with the HTML and JS code and affect parts of them - for example the way I passed data from the template to the JS uses features of Twig

Comment: @DarkBee you are right this has nothing to do with twig, codeigniter or php but this is my first question here so i hope you will forgive my mistake. I just wanted to describe it better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you must add the related currency ID to every country row.
So I assume  that the country row is something like this:

> id
> description
> currencyId

Then every time you choose a value in the *country select* you can obtain also the related currency id.
To keep the code simple I've assumed all the currency rows are passed to the view, but I've replaced the related select with a hidden input because in this scenario it doesn't seem useful to allow the user to change the currency after it has been set by the country (otherwise the request should be explained better).

In the *x-data* I've added a *currency* attribute and a *currencyData* that will contains the *currencyArray* data
In the *x-init* I've filled the *currencyData* array tranforming the backend *currencyArray* to a JSON consumable by the JS JSON.parse, using Twig filters (**NOTE: I can't test Twig, but it should work**)

I've stored the *currencyId* in each related option using *data-currency-id* attribute

On the *change event* the *currency* attribute of your Alpine object is filled reading the *data-currency-id* of the selected option

The hidden *currency field* is filled automatically since it is linked to the Alpine *currency* attribute using *x-model*
The description of the selected currency is filled searching the selected currency *id* in the *currencyData* Alpine attribute

Here we are at the limit of keeping all the JS code inside the HTML. When the code becomes more complex it will be appropriate to use an external object as shown [here](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data)

```twig
<div x-data="{ country: '', currency: '', currencyData: []}"
     x-init="currencyData = JSON.parse('{{ currencyArray|json_encode()|e("js") }}');"
>

    <div class="form-group">
    
        <label for="country">{{'country'|translate}}</label>
        
        <select id="country" name="country" class="form-select" aria-label="country" 
                x-model="country"
                @change="currency = $event.target.options[$event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.currencyId"
        >
            <option value=""></option>
    
            {% for country in countryArray %}
            
                <option value="{{ country.id }}" data-currency-id="{{ country.currencyId }}">
                    {{ country.description|capitalize|translate  }}
                </option>
                
            {% endfor %}
            
         </select>
         
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label>{{'currrency'|translate}}</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency" x-model="currency">

        <span x-text="() => {let c = currencyData.filter(row => row.id == currency); return c.length ? c[0].name + ' - ' + c[0].description : '';}"></span>

    </div>


     <br>
     Country: <span x-text="country"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it meant a lot to me to better understand how it works.